# How to repeat events with the calendar module?

Tags: datetime

I have installed the calendar module. I create a content type call **Events** and I added a **Date** field using the **Pop-up Calendar** control type. So when I create a event node I'm able to give it a Date. So far so good.

Now I need to have something like "repeat every day", "repeat every month", "repeat every year".

Can I accomplish this with the calendar module? Do I need to install another module?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that Date repeat API is checked on your module listing page